# Antiderivatives with acceleration, velocity, and displacement

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to work through this question and I'm not sure if I've done it right; I was wondering if anyone would be able to take a quick look at my work.

Here is the question:

A ball falls from a 12 metre building with acceleration a(t)=−g, where g the gravitational constant. Leave your answers in terms of g.

(a) You're 2 metres tall and are standing on the ground below the building. How many seconds do you have to get out of the way before the ball lands on your head?

(b) If you don't get out of the way, how fast will the ball be moving when it lands on your head?

(c) Where was the ball when it was moving with half the speed it lands on your head with?

And this is what I've done so far:

a(t) = -g

v(t) = -gt

x(t) = -1/2(gt^2)

**For (a)**

10 = 1/2gt^2
t^2 = 20/g
t = sqrt(20/g)

**For (b)**

v(sqrt(20/g)) = -g(sqrt(20/g)) meters/second

**For (c)**

I haven't done this part, but would it be accurate to find t when v = half of -g*sqrt(20/g) and plug that into the equation for x(t)?

Any help is greatly appreciated!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: please edit after 10= ... , t^2= ..., t=... then (a) is ok.

Comment: All steps is good.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

All steps is good.

You should get: $$t_2 = {1 \over 2} t_1$$and: $$x_2 = {1 \over 4} x_1$$